# Return anything between a pair of integers using reqular expressions

Tags: python

So far this is my solution

```
import re


def has_three_question_marks(word):
    regex_pattern = re.compile(r"\d(\D+)\d")
    matches = regex_pattern.findall(word)
    for match in matches:
        print(match)

print(has_three_question_marks("arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5"))
```

the problem with this solution is that it returns matches between 6 and 4, 5 and 5 but doesn't return whats between 4 and 5.

Comment: Replace second `\d` with `(?=\d)`

Comment: `re.findall('\d[^0-9]+(?=\d)',"arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your current regex doesn't match the middle part is because matches overlap: the trailing digit of your first match is the leading digit of the second match.

Try positive lookahead in the end:

```
regex_pattern = re.compile(r"\d(\D+)(?=\d)")
```

This way the match won't include the trailing digit and the matches won't overlap.

Comment: I think this answer would be improved by an explanation of why this is necessary.

Comment: Thank you this helped what does (?=\d) do exactly

Comment: `(?=\d)` is a positive lookahead: it matches if there is a digit (`\d`) after that point but doesn't include the digit into the match.